# Clean up excel data with python using pandas package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have read an xls file into Python with pandas using pd.read_excel

I am trying to cleanup my data but I'm way out of my league.

There is a blank line between every record. In the example pic it's excel row 4, 9 and 11.

There is a comments column, designated in the example (see link) as "col_F". Every record has at least one cell that contains text. The person that created this xls file split longer comments into multiple cells.

I would like to concatenate all of the data in col_F for a particular record into one cell.

I will also trim out blank records once I figure out how to properly concatenate col_F.

I am using Python version 3.5.0, numpy 1.12.0 and pandas 0.19.2

Here is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel("C:/blah/blahblah/file.xls", header=0, nrows=10000)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I appreciate any suggestion or insight!!

Thanks!

How the raw data looks:
[image]

Update:
This is how my data looks when I load into Python
[image: raw data read into python]

This is what my desired outcome would look like:
[image: what I would like dataframe to look like when finished]

Comment: Hints for you or aspiring an answer: load your df, replace blanks by np.nan, dropna('all' axis=1), ffill(), groupby(col A to E).apply(lambda x: '\n'.join(x)).reset_index()

Comment: Can you also attach or give a link to download the excel sheet here also?

Comment: I have updated my question to try to reduce some of the ambiguity of my initial question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out!!!
Big shout out to the Norfolk Data Science Club for the helping hand.

Import pandas, sqlite and os packages

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
import os
```

Specify filepaths and filenames

```
filepath = "C:/blah/blahblah/randomfolder"
filename = "raw_data.xlsx"
filePathFileName = filepath + "/" + filename
outputPathFileName = filepath + "/cleaned_" + filename
outputFileName = "cleaned_" + filename
```

Use pandas to read in excel file.

```
df = pd.read_excel(filePathFileName, header=0, nrows=14)
```

remove blank rows

```
df.dropna(how='all', inplace=True)
```

fill in the gaps in our data

```
df.ffill(inplace=True)
```

create a sqlite database and a connection to the sqlite database

```
con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
con.isolation_level = None
cur = con.cursor()
```

create a table for our data in sqlite

```
df.to_sql('example_data', con)
```

SQL query to aggregate our data

```
df_pdsql = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT col_A, col_B, col_C, col_D, col_E, GROUP_CONCAT(col_F, ' ') AS col_F FROM example_data GROUP BY col_A", con)
```

write our df to xlsx file

```
df_pdsql.to_excel(outputPathFileName, sheet_name='test', index=False)
```

let user know where file is located

```
print("Your new file is located in: " + outputPathFileName)
```

close connection to sqlite database

```
con.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really crude solution that I wrote where @Boud explained in the comment. I create example data here first:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['record1', '10', 'date1', 'optional', 'comment'], 
    ['', '', '', '', 'comment continued'], 
    ['', '', '', '', ''], 
    ['record2', '100', 'date2', '', 'comment'], 
    ['', '', '', '', 'comment continued'], 
    ['', '', '', '', 'comment continued'], 
    ['', '', '', '', 'comment continued'], 
    ['', '', '', '', ''],
    ['record3', '10000', 'date3', '', 'comment']], 
    columns=['col_A', 'col_B', 'col_C', 'col_D', 'col_F'])
df.replace('', np.nan, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Note that blank here should be filled with `NaN` instead of blank space. Basically, first, you can drop the row that you don't use first using `dropna`.

```
df.dropna(axis=0, how='all', inplace=True) # drop NaN by row
```

Then you can fill `col_A` by previous records.

```
new_col = []
row_name = ''
for r in df.col_A:
    if not pd.isnull(r):
        row_name = r
    new_col.append(row_name)
df.col_A = new_col
```

After than, you can group other columns by applying `groupby` function to column A and aggregate others columns by joining string as follows.

```
gr = df.groupby('col_A')

def join_str(x):
    x = list(map(str, x))
    x = [e for e in x if str(e) != 'nan']
    return ' '.join(x)

gr.agg({'col_B' : join_str, 
        'col_C': join_str, 
        'col_D': join_str, 
        'col_F': join_str}).reset_index()
```